# Can't load modules from anaconda environment into pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am trying to use a anaconda environment with pycharm. I did setup the environment from settings. If I call `import numpy as np` I get this error:

```
 D:\Anaconda3\envs\ml_test\python.exe D:/fac/python/b/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/fac/python/b/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\ml_test\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\ml_test\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

yes the environment does contain the numpy module

edit: fixed it by reinstalling anaconda

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the pycharm interpreter settings

Comment: @Prometheus https://imgur.com/a/ZvOsUHB

Comment: Try PyCharm 2019.1 EAP https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/ There is a known PyCharm issue fixed there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234.

Comment: Did you activate the conda environment? If not, could you confirm if activating it resolve your problem?

Comment: I had the same issue, several times; env is activated

Answer (score 0):

1. cd d:\Anaconda3\Scripts\
2. open CMD in folder
3. in terminal, type : conda list to obtain the packages installed using conda.
   for the packages that pip recognizes, type : pip list
   Numpy find in list?
4. Try conda install -n  , e.g. 
   conda install -n ml_test numpy

And, **you can** create anaconda ENV with python **3.6** for experiments and see https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy ?

May be access from another Anaconda environment to Pycharm will be resolve the issue or be clarification of the true source of the problem ?

*Sorry for possibly inaccurate grammar. I did my best :)*